# Looking for a good and durable tablet

Tags: drawing-tablet, hardware-recommendation

I'm looking for a decent tablet to use for my hobby drawing. So I need something that is a decent replacement for pen and paper and has a good life time (minimum 2 years). I was interested in Wacom's Intuos 4 but heard it's nibs spend too easily.

Comment: As far as tablets go, you really only have two choices, okay 3.... 1) ANY brand other than Wacom and regret the purchase. 2) A Wacom Bamboo.... good but may want to upgrade later. 3) Wacom Intuos... happy camper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can afford wacom intuos, buy it.

If lifetime is a big concern then even more if not already, wacom is the choice.
They have most accessories available ( especially for intuos )

Also, the lifetime for one pen nib is around 1 year depending on how much you use it and how you use it aand what pen nibs you use. ( one pen nib can last from one year to +4 depending on how heavy user you are )

My pesonal favorite and the most long lasting pen nib is the stroke nib.
( they sell these separately in packs of 5 which more or less means 5 years ) 
Without checking details for intuos 4, the package does include at least one of these stroke nibs.

Also they do sell overlays separately as well. Those may peel like onions in heavy usage.

[image]

Comment: I think that's the first time I've ever seen nibs that enlarged. It took me a few seconds to figure out that's what they were!

Answer (score 3):

I use monoprice graphic tablet. It only costs about 50 dollars and is very pressure sensitive. Also, its nibs cost like a buck for 5.
It doesn't have tilt or rotation functionality though.
But it is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

well personally I like Huion tablets. 
Unlike most of the other brands in the market, Huion has their own factory to make the tablets, which enables them to offer good quality and good price.
You may check the price in newegg.com and compare the specifications with the other brands.